# how to check if all elements on subvalue of array is equal to a value

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [on] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [on] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [on] => 2
        )

)
```

I would like the following:

1. if `[on]=>2` on all the sub-array,  return **$result = 2**
2. if one of the sub-array has `[on]=>1`, return **$result = 1**

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Have tried this, but it doesn't correct for the 1st requirment

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){

    if(in_array(2, $val)){

        $result =  2;

    }else if(in_array(1, $val)){

        $result =  1;

    }

}
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are the only available values for `['on']` always going to be `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 2):

what if 1. and 2. are both not met

```
function get_value( $array ){
    foreach( $array as $item ){
        if ( $item['on'] == 1 ){ return 1; }
        if ( $item['on'] != 2 ){ return FALSE; }
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrayelements as $arrayelement) {
    if($arrayelement['on'] == 2) {
        $result = 2;
        return $result;
    }

    if($arrayelement['on'] == 1) {
        $result = 1;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad, sleepy head here on me

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your question: here is mine! :)
With the following function you get an array of unwanted values if both are not satisfied.
You might be more precise in telling us what you would like to obtain in this case.

```
function my_check($array, $desired_value_for_all, $known_unwanted_value)
{
    $not_desired = array_diff(
        array_unique(
            array_map(
                create_function(
                    '$nested',
                    'return $nested["on"];'
                ),
                $array
            )
        ),
        array($desired_value_for_all)
    );

    if (empty($not_desired))
        return $desired_value_for_all;

    elseif (in_array($known_unwanted_value, $not_desired))
        return $known_unwanted_value;

    else
        return $not_desired;
}
```

Examples 1:

```
$array = array
(
    array
    (
        'id' => 10,
        'on' => 2
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 15,
        'on' => 2
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 20,
        'on' => 2
    )
);
var_dump(my_check($array, 2, 1));

Output:
int 2
```

Examples 2:

```
$array = array
(
    array
    (
        'id' => 10,
        'on' => 2
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 15,
        'on' => 1
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 20,
        'on' => 2
    )
);
var_dump(my_check($array, 2, 1));

Output:
int 1
```

Examples 3:

```
$array = array
(
    array
    (
        'id' => 10,
        'on' => 4
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 15,
        'on' => 2
    ),

    array
    (
        'id' => 20,
        'on' => 3
    )
);
var_dump(my_check($array, 2, 1));

Output:
array
    0 => int 4
    2 => int 3
```